# How many times can you make count += 1 in one second with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to measure how many times i can make "count = count + 1" in one second. But this function breaks browser. Anyone can say why is it happening or have a better method to calculate it?

```
function counter(){
   var count = 0;
   var trs = true;
   while(trs){
      count = count + 1;
      setTimeout(() => {trs = false;}, 1000);
   }
   console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded without preemption. Async functions don't run until lthe function returns.

Comment: But the function won't return until the async function changes the variable, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: See [Jake Archibald: In The Loop - JSConf.Asia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0).

Comment: No problem. It's just an FYI to let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it crashes is because of infinite loop. JavaScript is event driven + single threaded and in JavaScript execution model, the function must finish before it yields control to another function. Thus, the code `while (trs) {...}` never yields control to the function defined in `setTimeout` because it never finishes. `trs` is always `true`.

Nice visualization on how the JavaScript execution model works: https://blog.avenuecode.com/understanding-the-javascript-concurrency-model

Here's a better way to do it:

```
function counter() {
  var count = 0
  var start = Date.now()
  var end = start + 1000
  while (Date.now() <= end) {
    count = count + 1
  }
  console.log(count)
}
```

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a number, you don't need to convert it with `+`.

Comment: I like this answer and the way of thinking, but isn't it measuring 3 operations (`condition check`, `Date.now()` and `count=count+1`) instead of only the `count = count + 1` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an infinite loop over there. Now, since javascript is single-threaded, the browser will get stuck performing that infinite loop, which may cause the cache filling up very quickly and cause a crash (or not re-render anything).

First, generally speaking, it is better to create the `setTimeout` only once, before you call `while`:

```
   var count = 0;
   var trs = true;
   setTimeout(() => {trs = false;}, 1000);
   while(trs){
      count = count + 1;
   }
   console.log(count);
```

However, this will also cause a crash.

You can try to measure the operations differently, measure how much time it takes for a single `count = count + 1` operation to run, then find how many of these can be executed in a second (Although it is not the same as running X consecutive operations, which another parameters could influence the result, but I am assuming you care about a single operation or single function you want to measure).

```
   var count = 0;
   var t0 = performance.now()
   count = count + 1;
   var t1 = performance.now()
   console.log(1000/(t1 - t0));
```

If you want it to be inside a loop, you can also include the value check (with if), which the `while` does before executing its block.

```
   var count = 0;
   var trs=true;
   var t0 = performance.now()
   if(trs==true){
      count = count + 1;
   }
   var t1 = performance.now()
   console.log(1000/(t1 - t0));
```